# CAS SSO with one machine

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, cas

In every Tutorial I find a Installation of CAS Single-Sign-On with two machines.
Is it possible to install the client and the CAS SSO Server on only one machine ? And how ?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I think is to make two virtual machine( like Vmware ) in one machine. You cloud install client in one vmware, and install server in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. What doc are you referring to?

Always consult the official docs:
http://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Maven-Overlay-Installation.html